# Almost Riemannian foliation

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, foliations

A Foliation $\mathcal{F}$ on a  Riemannian manifold is called almost Riemannian foliation if $$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad  \exists  \delta >0  $$ such that for every leaf $L$  and every geodesic $\gamma $  starting an arbitrary point  $p\in L$ with $ (\gamma'(0), \mathcal{F}) \leq \delta$ we have $ (\gamma'(t), \mathcal{F})\leq \epsilon $  for  all parameter $t$ for which the geodesic $\gamma(t)$ is defined.

**Note:** In  an inner product space  $W$ with inner product $\langle \; \rangle$ and  for a  vector $V\in W$ and  a subspace $F\subset W$ the notation $(V,F)$ is defined as
$$(V,F)=\inf_{f\in F} \frac{\langle V,f\rangle}{|V||f|}$$ So we apply this definition to $V=\gamma'(t),  F=D\mathcal{F}$,  where $D\mathcal{F}$ is the  distribution tangent to the foliation.

> Does every almost Riemannian foliation admit a metric for which the foliation is  a  Riemannian foliation?